# how can i change it to touch event so that it will work on ipad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this is my code

```
onmouseout="if ($find('MainContent_ctl01_txtInsDate') != null) $find('MainContent_ctl01_txtInsDate').buttonMouseOut(event);"
onmouseup="if ($find('MainContent_ctl01_txtInsDate') != null) $find('MainContent_ctl01_txtInsDate').customButtonMouseUp(event);"
onmousedown="if ($find('MainContent_ctl01_txtInsDate') != null) $find('MainContent_ctl01_txtInsDate').customButtonMouseDown(event);"
```

Comment: HTML belongs in `.html` files, CSS belongs in `.css` files, JS belongs in `.js` files.

Comment: i just want to change it to touch up and touch down but i don't know how to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) wich supports [touch events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) for mobile devices.